# Complex sum of squares of vector fields (hypoelliptic operators)

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, harmonic-analysis

Consider a compact $M$ of dimension $n$. Consider real smooth vector fields $X_0, X_1, X_2,..., X_n$ on $M$ and consider the differential operator $\mathcal{L}_1 = \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i^2 + X_0.$
Now, by a result of Rothschild and Stein (see [here](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=436223), Theorems 16 and 18), if the commutators of weight $\leq r$ of the above vector fields generate $T_x(M)$ for all $x \in M$, then $\mathcal{L}_1$ is hypoelliptic with loss of $\frac{2}{r}$ derivatives.

My question is, is something known for vector fields with complex coefficients? For example, consider the differential operator $\mathcal{L}_2 = \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i^2 + i X_0,$
where the commutators of weight $\leq r$ of the above vector fields generate $T_x(M)$ for all $x \in M$. Is it known what the loss is in this case? If a general result is not known, I would also highly appreciate references where specific examples are computed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you want the i in front of X_0 in your question? After all, Re(iX_0u, u) = 0 for real X_0, or at least is an L^2 norm of u. So I doubt that the answer to your question is affirmative as you state it.